How to plot 4D graphs using plotly?
I'm trying to figure out a way to plot my 4D data using plotly, and it looks crazy to me that there are no references online for this.
What I'm trying to achieve is a simple interface with 3 drop-down menus for selecting the value on the three axes, and possibly a fourth one to select the slice of the 4th axis to be shown.
However I can't find any reference for doing this, and the only code I was able to code is not working and debugging on plotly can be painful.
Here's my code so far:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Load data
data = pd.read_csv("tempTable.csv")
data["lambda"] = 1. / data["phi"]

# Define variables and ranges
axis = ["p", "Tu", "phi", "egr"]
ranges = {a: np.unique(data[a].to_numpy()) for a in axis}
xaxis, yaxis, zaxis = 3, 1, 2  # Default axis selections
waxis = [x for x in range(len(axis)) if x not in [xaxis, yaxis, zaxis]][0]
isoID = 0

subData = data.loc[data[axis[waxis]] == ranges[axis[waxis]][isoID]]  # Get the slice along waxis
var = "Su"

# Initial figure
fig = px.scatter_3d(subData.loc[subData["completed"]],
                    x=axis[xaxis],
                    y=axis[yaxis],
                    z=axis[zaxis],
                    color=var,
                    color_continuous_scale="turbo",
                    range_color=[0.0, subData.loc[subData["completed"], var].to_numpy().max()])

# Function to update axis in the plot
def create_3d_trace(xaxis, yaxis, zaxis):
    waxis = [x for x in range(len(axis)) if x not in [xaxis, yaxis, zaxis]][0]
    subData = data.loc[data[axis[waxis]] == ranges[axis[waxis]][isoID]]
    return go.Scatter3d(
        x=subData.loc[subData["completed"], axis[xaxis]],
        y=subData.loc[subData["completed"], axis[yaxis]],
        z=subData.loc[subData["completed"], axis[zaxis]],
        mode="markers",
        marker=dict(
            size=3,
            color=subData.loc[subData["completed"], var],
            colorscale="turbo",
            colorbar=dict(title=var),
            cmin=0.0,
            cmax=subData.loc[subData["completed"], var].to_numpy().max(),
        )
    )


# Add initial trace
fig = go.Figure(data=[create_3d_trace(xaxis, yaxis, zaxis)])

# Create dropdown menus
dropdown_x = [
    dict(label=f"X: {ax}", method="update", args=[{"x": [subData.loc[subData["completed"], ax]]}, {"title": f"X-axis: {ax}"}])
    for ax in axis
]
dropdown_y = [
    dict(label=f"Y: {ax}", method="update", args=[{"y": [subData.loc[subData["completed"], ax]]}, {"title": f"Y-axis: {ax}"}])
    for ax in axis
]
dropdown_z = [
    dict(label=f"Z: {ax}", method="update", args=[{"z": [subData.loc[subData["completed"], ax]]}, {"title": f"Z-axis: {ax}"}])
    for ax in axis
]

# Add menus to layout
fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            buttons=dropdown_x,
            direction="down",
            showactive=True,
            x=0.1,
            xanchor="left",
            y=1.15,
            yanchor="top",
        ),
        dict(
            buttons=dropdown_y,
            direction="down",
            showactive=True,
            x=0.3,
            xanchor="left",
            y=1.15,
            yanchor="top",
        ),
        dict(
            buttons=dropdown_z,
            direction="down",
            showactive=True,
            x=0.5,
            xanchor="left",
            y=1.15,
            yanchor="top",
        ),
    ],
    scene=dict(
        xaxis=dict(title=axis[xaxis]),
        yaxis=dict(title=axis[yaxis]),
        zaxis=dict(title=axis[zaxis]),
    )
)

# Show the figure
fig.show() ```
However, the values shown are a single slice of "p", so setting one axis on p won't show a 3D graph but only a 2D plane on a 3D figure


You can use plotly and dash for the slider and dropdowns. The process is not straightforward, maybe another user has a cleaner solution.
from dash import Output, Input

Firstly, I randomly generated data for your situation as follows:
# Define unique values for each axis
unique_p = np.linspace(1, 100, 5)       # 5 unique pressure values
unique_Tu = np.linspace(10, 50, 4)      # 4 unique Tu values
unique_phi = np.linspace(0.1, 1.0, 6)   # 6 unique phi values (avoiding zero)
unique_egr = np.linspace(5, 25, 3)      # 3 unique EGR values

# Generate random data
num_points = 1000
p = np.random.choice(unique_p, size=num_points)
Tu = np.random.choice(unique_Tu, size=num_points)
phi = np.random.choice(unique_phi, size=num_points)
egr = np.random.choice(unique_egr, size=num_points)
Su = np.random.uniform(0, 100, size=num_points)
completed = np.random.choice([True, False], size=num_points, p=[0.7, 0.3])

# Create DataFrame
data = pd.DataFrame({
    "p": p,
    "Tu": Tu,
    "phi": phi,
    "egr": egr,
    "Su": Su,
    "completed": completed
})

# Calculate 'lambda'
data["lambda"] = 1.0 / data["phi"]

Then you need to set up dash layout:
app = Dash(__name__)

axis = ["p", "Tu", "phi", "egr"]
ranges = {a: np.unique(data[a].to_numpy()) for a in axis}

app.layout = html.Div([
    # Dropdowns for X, Y, Z axes
    html.Div([
        html.Label('X-axis:'),
        dcc.Dropdown(id='xaxis-dropdown', options=[{'label': ax, 'value': ax} for ax in axis], value=axis[0]),
    ], style={'width': '24%', 'display': 'inline-block'}),

    html.Div([
        html.Label('Y-axis:'),
        dcc.Dropdown(id='yaxis-dropdown', options=[{'label': ax, 'value': ax} for ax in axis], value=axis[1]),
    ], style={'width': '24%', 'display': 'inline-block'}),

    html.Div([
        html.Label('Z-axis:'),
        dcc.Dropdown(id='zaxis-dropdown', options=[{'label': ax, 'value': ax} for ax in axis], value=axis[2]),
    ], style={'width': '24%', 'display': 'inline-block'}),

    # Dropdown and Slider for 4th dimension
    html.Div([
        html.Label('Slice along:'),
        dcc.Dropdown(id='slice-dropdown', options=[{'label': ax, 'value': ax} for ax in axis], value=axis[3]),
        dcc.Slider(id='slice-slider', min=0, max=0, step=1, value=0, marks={}),
    ], style={'width': '24%', 'display': 'inline-block'}),

    # 3D Scatter Plot
    dcc.Graph(id='3d-scatter-plot')
])

Update Slider Based on 4th Axis Selection:
from dash import Output, Input

@app.callback(
    [Output('slice-slider', 'min'),
     Output('slice-slider', 'max'),
     Output('slice-slider', 'marks'),
     Output('slice-slider', 'value')],
    Input('slice-dropdown', 'value')
)
def update_slice_slider(slice_axis):
    unique_values = ranges[slice_axis]
    marks = {i: str(v) for i, v in enumerate(unique_values)}
    return 0, len(unique_values)-1, marks, 0

Plot the 3D Scatter based on your selected slice:
import plotly.graph_objects as go

@app.callback(
    Output('3d-scatter-plot', 'figure'),
    [Input('xaxis-dropdown', 'value'),
     Input('yaxis-dropdown', 'value'),
     Input('zaxis-dropdown', 'value'),
     Input('slice-dropdown', 'value'),
     Input('slice-slider', 'value')]
)
def update_graph(xaxis, yaxis, zaxis, slice_axis, slice_idx):
    # Ensure all axes are unique
    if len({xaxis, yaxis, zaxis, slice_axis}) < 4:
        return go.Figure()

    # Get current slice value
    waxis_value = ranges[slice_axis][slice_idx]

    # Filter data
    subData = data[(data[waxis] == waxis_value) & data["completed"]]

    # Create 3D scatter plot
    fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter3d(
        x=subData[xaxis],
        y=subData[yaxis],
        z=subData[zaxis],
        mode='markers',
        marker=dict(
            size=5,
            color=subData["Su"],
            colorscale='turbo',
            colorbar=dict(title='Su'),
            opacity=0.8
        )
    ))

    fig.update_layout(
        scene=dict(
            xaxis_title=xaxis,
            yaxis_title=yaxis,
            zaxis_title=zaxis,
        ),
        title=f'Slice of {waxis} = {waxis_value}'
    )
    return fig

Run:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)

Images of Slice Plots:



I didnt't quite manage to replicate your example. Altough it seems to really solve my problem... Do you mind sharing the full code?

3D = x, y, z
4D = x y, z, t (via animation)
5D = x, y, z, t, colour
6D = x, y, z, t, colour, symbol
7D = x, y, z, t, colour, symbol, symbol size

you could also look to add facet or marginal plots ?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@DaveG, Please incorporate a coding solution/example relevant to the problem into your answer, and I will retrieve my downvote
